# How to replace '/' with '\\' using QString replace()?

Tags: qt, path, qt4, cross-platform

Can anyone help with following? Suppose I have a QString with a filepath stored of a certain file, I want to replace the `/`(slashes) from it with `\\`(double backslashes) I tried:

```
mystring.replace("/","\\");
```

But it only puts a single `\` instead of `\\`

String before replacement: `D:/myfiles/abc.zip`

String after replacement: `D:\myfiles\abc.zip`

Expected string: `D:\\myfiles\\abc.zip`

Comment: Not really sure, but as far as I remember QFile/QFileInfo happily work with any directory separator

Comment: I'm surprised this actually compiles. Aren't you escaping the closing `"` with the third `\\`? And what language do you use? C++?

Comment: But adb needs '\\' :p
I am making a automated adb tool :)

Comment: @CodesInChaos Someone edited my post, thats not real code I typed when making this thread, my code is mystring.replace("/", "\\");

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to use:

```
mystring.replace("/","\\\\");
```

The compiler uses `\` as an escape character in strings (for things like `\t`, `\n` or `\r`) so that `\\` is actually turned into `\`. If you need two backslashes, you need to start with four.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same in QML string?

Comment: @user3417815, that's a separate question so should be *asked* as a separate question :-) You'll get a better response with a new question *everyone* sees rather than a comment probably only I will see, especially since I haven't done any QML.

Answer (score 30):

If you want to convert paths to Windows format, you could simply use [QDir::toNativeSeparators()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qdir.html#toNativeSeparators):

```
qDebug() << QDir::toNativeSeparators("c:/windows/path"); // Prints "c:\windows\path"
```

Answer (score -1):

1) Why do you want to replace them, AFAIR forward slashes work in file operations too (irrespective of OS).
2) Did you try to read the docs - for example why `\\` results in single backslash?

Comment: forward slashes don't work when doing adb operations in a Android Phone, therefore they need to be replace by double backslashes(even single backslash doesn't work :p)

Comment: You could have read the explanation posted by paxdiablo above in the docs, it clearly describes the use of single `\\` as an escape character. Each escape character escapes ONE character following it.